# What to do about a downvoted question that adds value?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I posted a question on [Security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152813/what-hardware-can-a-user-mode-process-access) and it got downvoted (once) probably by the first guy that left a comment. After some more research I could answer the question myself. All that is fine!

Now I think this question adds value for the community since googling for it does not give any good results.

*Also I think it is indeed valid as it is posted, since the answer I found is pretty much what I expected when posing the question (e.g. it is indeed OS independent contrary to what probably got me the downvote).*

My guess is that it won't get any attention any more since it has an answer (which I will accept once I can) and is rated -1. Is there a way to get it voted up? *(Not to get rep but because of the value I think it adds)*

Or maybe I am reading this wrong and my question is actually bad for some reason that I cannot see right now, should I repost it (in a better way) knowing the answer?

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on the Meta of Security.se?

Comment: In general: you only need to judge the merit of the post and vote accordingly. Current votes, reputation shouldn't be considered,

Comment: Don't repost it.  Leave it and, if it actually has value (looks like it), it will gain votes over time.

Comment: @rene You are right I might have asked on Meta.Security.se wether this particular question is worth reposting and what do do about it. But this question on Meta.se is intended to be about the general case with the Security.se question as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question or answer is truely of any value, trust that other users will eventually up-vote the content. You can also attract more attention by posting a *bounty*, but you should only do this when you intend to attract the attention of a *higher-quality answer*.

There are other elements that could help, in this case and others. I will list them, below.

---

> it got downvoted (once) probably by the first guy that left a comment. **...** (e.g. it is indeed OS independent contrary to what probably got me the downvote)

If you believe the comment is incorrect, you might want to request clarification from the user who posted it. It appears you have attempted to do so, but commenting does not necessarily alert the user to the reply. They are probably oblivious to your question. To alert users, mention them directly with *@username*. If you were to want to alert me to a comment, for example, you would start the comment with "*@Gnemlock*".

The comment in question was posted *before* your last edit; if that user really *did* downvote your question, they would have done so *prior* to the edit. All votes can be altered after a revision to the question.

---

> My guess is that it won't get any attention any more since it has an answer (which I will accept once I can) and is rated -1

If your question and answer provide useful information, a vote of -1 should not have any real bearing on it's 'accessibility'. Other users should still be able to find your question. Note that if your question has *severe* issues, a greater negative score (-5 on the sites I am familiar with - this may change per site) will remove your question from *normal* view; only users with a reputation of 10,000k and moderators will be able to view it.

I do not think a negative score necessarily persuades users away from your question, either. If the content is relevant to someone's interest, I would still expect them to have a look. Furthermore, some users may deliberately view down-voted questions, just to see if there is any obvious issues they can fix (I sometimes do this, myself).

---

> Or maybe I am reading this wrong and my question is actually bad for some reason that I cannot see right now, should I repost it (in a better way) knowing the answer?

If a question is obviously of low quality, I would expect more than a single downvote. As of writing this answer, you seem to already have an upvote to balance out, anyway.

If you are unsure, ask in the relevant meta. Ask how your question could be improved, and take on any feedback you may receive, negative or otherwise. You should *not* repost the question; at best, you should edit your question with improvements.

All that said, here are some additional pointers, based off my review of your question and answer:

- Show research effort. Your question shows *no* research effort, and your answer seems to imply that given some basic research effort, you were able to find your answer on your own. Note that *"Shows no research effort"* is a hard written reason for valid downvotes. Note that if you think your question is still useful, you can provide an answer from the same page where you initially type up your question. Found the solution to a tough question without having to ask? Awesome. Ask and self-answer, anyway. If it is a tough question, you might help others.
- If you are unsure of the answer, I am unsure of the answer. I appreciate the ethical implication of confirming your uncertainty; however, you start your answer off by surrounding it in *serious doubt*, for somebody that is not already informed of the topic enough to make their own decision.
- Format goes a long way. I tend to use *italics* for emphasis; and I have tried to restrict my use, even then. **Bold** has a lot more contrast, and detracts from the quality of the answer, if used a lot. [WikiHow has a good page on the appropriate use of italics for reference](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Italics).

These are just some ideas. It seems that several users have noted the usefulness of your question, and that your answer seems correct. At the same time, as of typing this answer, no body has considered your answer to be worth upvoting.